Get attributes from polygons that intersect lines arcade expression
I'm trying to get attributes of a polygon and add them to the intersecting line.
Below is the script.
The problem is to add the attributes to the line where the intersection is the largest. It doesn't always return the attributes from the polygon where the line has the biggest intersection, it looks like it is returning random attributes.
// Get Geometry of the current feature from the main table
var currentGeometry = Geometry($feature);

// Get polygons from the 'commune' layer that intersects the current feature
var communePolygons = Intersects(FeatureSetByName($datastore, "COMMUNE"), currentGeometry);

// Initialize the variable to add the selected FACILITYID
var selectedFacilityID = null;
var maxOverlap = -1;

// Go through all the polygons 'commune' that intersect 'Main'
for (var communePolygon in communePolygons) {
var communeGeometry = Geometry(communePolygon);
var intersect = Intersection(currentGeometry, communeGeometry);

// Calculate the area of the intersection
var overlapArea = Area(intersect);

// Check if the intersection is the largest
if (overlapArea > maxOverlap) {
maxOverlap = overlapArea;
selectedFacilityID = communePolygon.INSEE_COM;
}

// If no polygon is dominant, we can get the FACILITYID of the first polygon met
if (IsEmpty(selectedFacilityID)) {
selectedFacilityID = communePolygon.INSEE_COM;
}
}

return IIf(!IsEmpty(selectedFacilityID), selectedFacilityID, "Error: No polygons 'commune' found.");


Code looks OK to me. You mention several times a "line" but your code appears to be all about polygons because the intersection() of a line with a polygon returns a line which has zero area. Maybe you have multipart geometry or your layers are different coordinate systems?

You're right for a line I should be using the Length()
